# I can't use the typeof operator - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I need to use the "typeof" operator but the browser returns me an error:

```
index.js:1 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
    at _typeof2 (index.js:1)
```

The error is returned regardless of where I will use this operator.
I was looking for similar problems on the internet, but I found nothing.

My dependencies:

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5"
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.4.1",
```

Edited:

https://pastebin.com/tWZxNBe9 - this is bundle code. In 99 line there is a probable problem.

Comment: Can you please add the code?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code does not matter. It can only be console.log(typeof []).

Comment: Quickest way to NOT get help. Tell those attempting to help that their requests are irrelevant. You don't know what _Maximum call stack size exceeded_ means, you've found nothing on the internet and you believe the code doesn't matter. OK, have a good day.

Comment: I've file index.js with only console.log(typeof []) and the issue still occurs. I do not know what to describe more ;>

Comment: @Ku3a Even if you drop it in the browser console on this website?  Or put it in index.js with no dependencies whatsoever?

Comment: @Brilliand Nope, in browser console all works fine.

Comment: The mere mention of _typeof2 is clear evidence that *something* is messing with your typeof operator.  You're gonna have to find it; we can't do much without you showing us the code that's affecting it.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/tWZxNBe9
This is a bundel code. In 99 line there is something with typeof but I do not know why it's there :D

Comment: @Ku3a I could definitely see that code causing the problem you're experiencing.  Put it in the question, and maybe someone will be able to explain why that code is there and how to make it do its job properly.

Comment: seems like babel adds own implementation of `typeof` to handle say Symbol that is not available in es2015. maybe workaround mentioned at https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/4125 will help

Comment: also https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3836 looks exactly as your case but happened 3+ years ago. maybe you've run into bug reveals